# 'tiny.weights' not displaying output - YOLOv3

Tags: python, yolo, darknet

I'm trying to run a yolo detection with the 'tiny.weights' and can't seem to get the desired output.

```
os.system('./darknet detector test cfg/coco.data cfg/yolov3-tiny.cfg tiny.weights data/dog.jpg')

plt.clf()
plt.imshow(mpimg.imread(os.path.join("predictions.jpg")))
plt.axis("on")
plt.show()
```

I should be getting my prediction boxes, and it's working with the regular weights, just not the 'tiny.weights'

[image: Normal 'yolov3.weights']

[image: 'tiny.weights']

Comment: Did you try running that command in terminal and check the result?